# error Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: in nojd.js simple app

Tags: node.js

Facing below error while creating a simple html, css application in node.js:
error Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

server.js code is :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

// Create a server
http.createServer( function (request, response) {  
// Parse the request containing file name
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

// Print the name of the file for which request is made.
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

// Read the requested file content from file system
fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);

     // HTTP Status: 404 : NOT FOUND
     // Content Type: text/plain
     response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  } else {  
     //Page found     
     // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
     // Content Type: text/plain
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});    

     // Write the content of the file to response body
     response.write(data.toString());       
  }

  // Send the response body 
  response.end();
 });   
}).listen(9999);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9999/');
```

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `path` module to identify the extension and set the `mime` type accordingly:

```
// require path module
var path = require('path');

// check for extenstion
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var ext = path.extname(pathname).substr(1);

// check extension and set mime type
// HTTP Status: 200 : OK
if (ext === 'css') {
  // check for css
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
} else {
  // Content Type: text/plain
  // maybe also check .html type
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
}

// Write the content of the file to response body
response.write(data.toString());
```